# Writing myletstar macro (hygiene) in Scheme

Tags: macros, scheme, racket, hygiene

I am trying to re-write `let*` hygiene macro, I have it as normal macro and I would like to have it as hygiene macro if it's possible. I don't have too much experience with this macro types. So I would really appreciate help. Also my another representation of working `let*` macro is not working, with same error as hygiene macro.

Working `let*`

```
(define-macro let*1
(lambda (assgn . body)
(let ((loop (gensym))
      (lst (gensym)))
  (let loop ((lst assgn))
     (if (null? lst)
         `(begin ,@body)
         `((lambda (,(caar lst))
             ,(loop (cdr lst)))
           ,(cadar lst)))))))
```

Not working hygiene `let*` -> **error: lambda: not an identifier in: (caar lst)**

```
(define-syntax let*2
(syntax-rules ()
((let*2 (set ...) body ...)
 (let loop ((lst '(set ...)))
   (if (null? lst)
       body ...
       ((lambda ((caar lst))
          (loop (cdr lst)))
        (cadar lst) 1))))))
```

Not working `let*`, but also having same error as the second one.

```
(define-macro let*3
(lambda (assgn . body)
(let ((loop (gensym))
      (lst (gensym)))
  `(let ,loop ((,lst assgn))
     (if (null? ,lst)
         (begin ,@body)
         ((lambda ((caar ,lst))
             (,loop (cdr ,lst)))
           (cadar ,lst)))))))
```

Apologize for little confusing question, I am stucked with this problem for some time already and caffeine isn't usefull anymore.

Some tests (I picked symbol names to test symbol-capture(I know I didn't had to)):

```
(let*1 ((body 10)
   (lst (+ body 1)))
  (list body lst))

(let*2 ((body 10)
    (lst (+ body 1)))
  (list body lst))

(let*3 ((body 10)
    (lst (+ body 1)))
  (list body lst))
```

**Edit:** Question is answered, added solution without using let by editing [Lief Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288439/leif-andersen) code

```
(define-syntax let*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((let*2 ([x1 e1][x2 e2] ...)body ...)
     ((lambda  (x1)
        (let* ([x2 e2] ...)
           body ...))
         e1))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second one is the closest. A hygenic `let*` macro can be written with [`define-syntax-rule`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html?q=define-syntax#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmisc..rkt%29._define-syntax-rule%29%29). (If you're writing this in an implementation of scheme rather than racket, you can also just compose `define-syntax` and `syntax-rule` for the same effect.)

```
(define-syntax-rule (let* ([x1 e1]
                           [x2 e2] ...)
                      body ...)
  (let ([x1 e1])
    (let* ([x2 e2] ...)
      body ...))
```

And if you're feeling really pedantic, you can make a hygenic `let` macro:

```
(define-syntax-rule (let ([x e] ...)
                      body ...)
  ((lambda (x ...) body ...) e ...))
```

Comment: Thank you for such a fast response. I was quite worried about using recursive in hygenic macro, and I'm not really good with using ellipses. Hygenic let macro is pretty easy.

Comment: Yup, you can (and frequently should) use recursion with a hygenic macro. Although do make sure there is a base case, or it will never finish expanding. ;)

Answer (score 1):

R6RS, Appendix B gives the [following definition](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-16.html#node_chap_B) of `let*`:

```
(define-syntax let*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((let* () body1 body2 ...)
     (let () body1 body2 ...))
    ((let* ((name1 expr1) (name2 expr2) ...)
       body1 body2 ...)
     (let ((name1 expr1))
       (let* ((name2 expr2) ...)
         body1 body2 ...)))))
```

Comment: I couldn't find any solution and I'm not sure how ellipses in Scheme works, thank you for this site, which I will surely find very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to `let*` I don't think hygiene is an issue. The names in the `let` you want to expose and you don't introduce any other bindings.

```scm
(require compatibility/defmacro)
(define-macro let*1
  (lambda (assgn . body)
    (let loop ((lst assgn))
      (if (null? lst)
          `(begin ,@body)
          `((lambda (,(caar lst))
              ,(loop (cdr lst)))
            ,(cadar lst))))))

(expand-once 
 #'(let*1 
     ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) 
       (list a b c)))

; ==> #'((lambda (a)
;          ((lambda (b)
;            ((lambda (c)
;               (begin
;                 (list a b c)))
;             3))
;          2))
;       1)
```

Seems ok for me. Now you could do the same using `syntax-rules`. This method doesn't use scheme language and thus you trying to do `(caar lst)` is assumed you want that **in the resulting expansion**.

```scm
(expand-once #'(let*2 ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) (list a b c)))
; ==> #'(let loop ((lst '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))))
;         (if (null? lst)
;             (list a b c)
;             ((lambda ((caar lst))
;                (loop (cdr lst)))
;              (cadar lst)
;              1)))
```

Notice how your code actually is copied verbatim into the resulting expandion. It's because everything that is not destructured in the pattern is assumed to be in the lexical scope of the syntax itself. Here is how to do it:

```scm
(define-syntax let*2
  (syntax-rules ()
    ;; handle stop condition (no more bindings)
    ((let*2 ()  body ...) 
     (begin body ...))
    ;; handle one expansion
    ((let*2 ((name expr) more-bindings ...) body ...)
     (let ((name expr))
       (let*2 (more-bindings ...)
         body ...))))) 
(expand-once 
 #'(let*2 
     ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3)) 
       (list a b c)))

; ==> #'((lambda (a) 
;          (let*2 ((b 2) (c 3)) 
;            (list a b c))) 1)
```

`expand-once` only does one level, but by using the macro expander you'll see it continues until all parts are expanded.

So when do you need hygiene? It's when you introduce bindings in your macro. The standard example is usually `swap!` that swaps the values of two bindings:

```scm
(define-syntax swap!
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((swap! var1 var2)
     (let ((tmp var1))
       (set! var1 var2)
       (set! var2 tmp)))))
```

With `syntax-rules` every binding not a pattern is though to be in the lexical scope of the macro and eveything not is a new binding that gets created new at each expansion. Thus I can safely do this:

```scm
(let ((tmp 1) (another 2))
  (swap! tmp another)
  (list tmp another))
; ==> (2 1)
```

With the old style you'd need this:

```scm
(define-macro swap!
  (lambda (var1 var2)
    (let ((tmp (gensym "tmp")))
      `(let ((,tmp ,var1))
         (set! ,var1 ,var2)
         (set! ,var2 ,tmp)))))
```

This works for the example above, but if I were to do:

```scm
(let ((set! 1) (let 2))
  (swap! set! let)
  (list set! let))
```

The syntax-rules one will evaluate to `(2 1)` while the `define-macro` one won't work.

Comment: I see, so you can re-write any macro to hygiene macro(even through it's not necessary)? I like your last example define-macro vs syntax-rules. I want to do most of macros by using hygiene, because sometimes I get lost in quasiquotes. I was wondering if there is something like macroexpand, like in Common Lisp.

Comment: @dyouteotyi `syntax-rules` can be very verbose sometimes. Racket has more than 2 different macro systems and the general one uses the racket language and is hygienic at the same time. In my answer you see I use `expand-once` and it and `expand` is the same as `macroexpand-1` and `macroexpand`. In addition you have the macro stepper in DrRacket which you can se every transformation step by step. That is the one I'm using most.